# Efficient way to transpose large categorical column to one-hot table row

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a varchar column containing ~ 8000 unique values and 500k rows.  I need the column transposed so that the column headers are the unique values and the values in the rows are 1 where the row has an entry with the header and 0 elsewhere.  This is sometimes referred to as one-hot-encoding.

I have tried pivoting the table to columns but, unsurprisingly, even on a very small subset of rows the operation is very inefficient. Is there an efficient way to do this in sql?

I would like to transpose the column Category,

```
Data1   Data2   Category
  0.1      24          A
  0.23     10          B
  0.21     11          B
```

to this output:

```
Data1   Data2   A   B
  0.1      24   1   0
  0.23     10   0   1       
  0.21     11   0   1
```

Comment: Can you show a cut down example? (E.g using `varchar(20)`)

Comment: So you want to end up with a resultset with ~8000 columns?

Comment: @AakashM Yes, I would have ~8000 columns

Comment: 8000 columns could be difficult to achieve since the max [Columns per SELECT statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432(v=sql.120).aspx) is 4,096.